# PHP - input type hidden to get id

Tags: php, html, select, hidden

i want when user select one student name to get the student id as a hidden input to use it in the next page , the problem is when i added this to my code it doesn't show all students list to select from , it shows only one student name ( the first one stored in the database ) m any ideas ? !
my code

```
  $sql = "SELECT s.Sname, e.PID , s.SID
                          from student AS s
                          INNER JOIN evaluator AS e                       
                          WHERE (e.EID1 = '$id' AND s.PID = e.PID) OR  (e.EID2 = '$id' AND s.PID = e.PID)
                          GROUP BY s.Sname  ";
         $result = mysql_query ($sql, $connection);

         echo "<tr><th >Student Name <font size='4'></font></th>";
         echo "<td><select id='Sname' name='Sname' >";

        echo "<option value='' selected='selected'>--</option> ";

        while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
   {

        echo "<option value='$row[Sname]' >$row[Sname]</option> ";
        echo " <input type ='hidden' name='SID' value='".$row['SID']."'  >;

   }
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you are creating multiple `<input>` with `name='SID'` and the receiving page will probably only accept the first one.  You need to create them as an array instead with `[]`

```
echo " <input type ='hidden' name='SID[]' value='".$row['SID']."'  ></option>";
//----------------------------------^^^^^^
```

In the receiving page, check the contents with `var_dump($_POST['SID'])`. It will be an array and you can iterate it with a `foreach()`.

I note that you are nesting `<input>` inside  `<option>`s. That is probably not a good approach ( I don't think it is valid HTML). Instead, store all the `SID` in an array and loop twice to create your inputs.

```
$ids = array();
while( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   // First make an array of ids
   $ids[] = $row;
}
```

Then loop over it twice, to build the select options, and the hidden inputs:

```
// <select> opened above...
// Inside the <select> tag already opened...
foreach ($ids as $id) {
  echo "<option value='$id[Sname]' >$id[Sname]</option> ";
}
// Close the <select>
// </select>

// Then later, loop to build the hidden inputs in the array format
foreach ($ids as $id) {
  echo " <input type ='hidden' name='SID[]' value='".$id['SID']."'  >";
}
```

---

*On the subject of valid HTML...* I also see a stray closing `</font>` in there.  `<font>` is deprecated, and instead you should be using CSS to define font properties.

#### Update after comments:

If you want to pass the SID along with the value (Sname) in the `<option>` then it is easiest to skip the hidden `<input>` entirely. Instead, pass both values in the `<option value>` attribute, separated by something like a `|`. In the PHP code that receives it, `explode()` them back into two values:

```
// In your original while loop:
// The value consists of both SID and Sname, separated by |
// Now, you have no need for the <input type='hidden' name='SID'> at all. Remove them.
echo "<option value='$row[SID]|$row[Sname]' >$row[Sname]</option> ";

// Then in the PHP script which receives the form values, explode() them:
// Both values come from the <select name='Sname'>
list($SID, $Sname) = explode("|", $_POST['Sname']);
// Now your variables $SID and $Sname hold the correct values
// If you need to reuse them, store into `$_SESSION
session_start();
$_SESSION['SID'] = $SID;
$_SESSION['Sname'] = $Sname;

// On other scripts, to read the values
session_start();
echo $_SESSION['SID'];
```

If you are unfamiliar with how to use `$_SESSION`, review [the manual on basic usage](https://www.php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php).  Long story short, you must call `session_start()` on each script that accesses `$_SESSION`, and you must do so *before* the script produces any output, including whitespace.  This is the standard method of sharing data between scripts.

Comment: or you can use another value for name attribute e.g. `name=\"".$row['SID']."\"`

Comment: i don't want the sid to be as an option , i want when the user select a student name his id taken as hidden input and store to use later .. hope u understand

Comment: @user1806136 See update above.  You can do this without the hidden inputs by passing _both_ SID and Sname in the `<option>`, delimited by `|` or other character.

Comment: now it read the id correctly , but the thing is that i have three pages i want the same data ( Sname and SID ) to pass there , should i put list($SID, $Sname) = explode("|", $_POST['Sname']); at each page ? or is there another way to pass this two values ?

Comment: because I had tried to put this explode() at the third page but it doesnt work out .. error says Undefined index: Sname + Undefined offset: 1

Comment: @user1806136 Relax, I'm not here every minute of the day. I have a family and responsibilities :)

Comment: If you need to pass it to other pages, store it into `$_SESSION` as I have added above.

Comment: This is now way outside the scope of your original question.  Logically, `$SID` does not exist until you set it with the `explode()` in the page the receives the form `$_POST`. So set it after the `explode()` just like it is above.

Comment: Excuse me??? You ask for additional help in a comment, then an hour later you post another comment _"hope to get any answer"_ with a sad emoticon, and I come back and _do_ help you even though you have gone far out of the bounds of your question, when there is _nothing_ in it for me, and continue to help you again today, and you're going to curse at me?  And not even accept the answer to this question? Wow.